# angularJs ng-repeat... dynamically ng-include, ng-controller, ng-init

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-controller, angularjs-ng-include, ng-init

I will hope do it.

```
<div ng-include="'templates/control/title.html'" ng-controller="titleCtrl" ng-init="ControlInit('00001')"></div>
<div ng-include="'templates/control/title.html'" ng-controller="titleCtrl" ng-init="ControlInit('00002')"></div>
<div ng-include="'templates/control/title.html'" ng-controller="titleCtrl" ng-init="ControlInit('00003')"></div>
```

So, ng-repeat done it.

```
<div ng-repeat="control in Controls" ng-include="'control.ctrlUrl'" ng-controller="control.ctrlName" ng-init="control.ctrlInit + '(' + control.ctrlCode + ')'"></div>
```

don't working...
Why not?

Please....Answer code... example...

Comment: what is the error you got ?

Comment: Please first read how to write a [MCV](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) question

Comment: error list
1. ng-controller need 'got a string'
2. ng-init do not working

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put `control.ctrlUrl` within `'` single quotes. Try this:

```
<div ng-repeat="control in Controls" ng-include="control.ctrlUrl" ng-controller="control.ctrlName" ng-init="control.ctrlInit + '(' + control.ctrlCode + ')'"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, that was a problem but it still won't work either. `ng-controller` will fail to load a controller with name `control.ctrlName`. `ng-controller` don't interpolate attributes.

Comment: You'll need to provide more code for me to help you out then